# node title preprocess_views_view_field();

Tags: theming, nodes

I want to save the node title in a variable using: `themename_preprocess_views_view_field()`, becuase I want to print a the node title above the field.

But when I try to save the title with:

```
themename_preprocess_views_view_field() {
$variables['node_title'] = $variables['field']->original_value ->    string;
}
```

I get Error: Cannot access protected property Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::$string in themename_preprocess_views_view_field() (line 123 of themes/custom/themename/themename.theme).

how can I save this variable so I can print it in the `views-view-field.html.twig` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The way to do this is to add an address **Field** in the **View** as **Content datasource: address** in the Admin GUI.

And select **Use entity field rendering**.

Under **REWRITE RESULTS**
 Select: **Override the output of this field with custom text**

And in the textbox I added in my case:

{{ title }}
{{ field_address }}